# Getting to Grips with Component Heirarchy in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, structure, components, hierarchy

Im learning React and pondering over the structure of the components. The following has me confused a bit.

- We are told that there should be a single source of truth.
- The owner component should pass the props / states to its responsibility (as some call 'ownee') components.

So, if my own whole app is one big component (owner) with lots of its responsibility (ownee) components, does that mean that that top level owner component will hold ALL the props and states. That would be a massive object.

As Im not initially using `states`, any changes to `props` would have to be passed to the 'owner' & then that component rendered again?

Clearly this is not right, right? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is why [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) or [something like it](https://github.com/rackt/redux) is really needed for a non-trivial React app.

Answer (score 1):

That interpretation is slightly off-mark. Your top level component doesn't need to be an all-knowing omniscient behemoth, simply because of the crucial difference between *props* and *state*. Any component is free to pick and control its own state, which it can pass down to its children. However, a prop for a component should not ideally be preserved in its state variable because that's what causes a duplicacy and violates the single source of truth paradigm. A prop is NOT owned by the component, it is owned by the ancestor which sent the prop down. On the contrary, it is natural and expected for a component to pass its state down as props to its children.

You will see that you can't do much without state, unless your app displays static content mostly. So when you start dealing with state, keep state where it belongs. Even with Flux there are ways to keep state relevant to the component to which it belongs.

Comment: Thanks @Hazardous, my confusion is that if all the components have ultimately a single parent, then clearly, that parent is the entry point. Im updating the post with a rough example. https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/getting-to-grips-with-component-heirarchy-in-react/2887

Comment: Your data model in the example isn't hierarchical,so it doesn't need to be sent down from the top component. It is perfectly acceptable for ParentComponent to have ChildComponent with the prop chromosome3 hard coded in it. Rationale is that GrandParent doesn't know about what chromosomes its skip level descendants will take. It can only govern the chromosomes of its children. Side comment on Redux, the state is indeed in one object, but there also, the top level component doesn't "distribute" it down. Internal components use various reducers as needed.

Comment: I disagree on the 'hard coded' part, that would make it static, what if I want to pass props. I cannot call the render function on it directly so the props have to be passed through the GrandParent. I do agree with your first point about hierarchy. Here is another question I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718629/using-react-without-states where Michelle has a good point on maintaining multiple components at the top level, the app structure doesnt necessarily need to be a pyramid.

Comment: Well it is hardcoded at the moment in the example you linked. The chromosome3 gets routed to the childcomponent. It could have come from GrandParent or Parent, wouldn't have mattered. Since the entire tree is being rendered within another surrogate top level component, GrandParent has no say on its descendants :).