# Using React without States

Tags: javascript, dom, optimization, reactjs, state

I am building the UI of an app and I am exploring updating the UI without having to use States. Would the following assertion be crudely correct?

*'We do not need States as all its doing is calling the render method automatically on the component when something within the state changes. We can achieve the same implementation by calling the render method on the relevant component ourselves.*

**We would still achieve all the same benefits of React (virtual DOM, rendering, painting optimisations etc)**'

Comment: Any application needs "state", without "state" you have no data, and without data, you can't do anything. What do you mean by "without state"?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Im being specific about React.js. A React component can have an immutable state which stores value / s. Whenever there is a change in state, the component is re-rendered automatically.

Comment: Right, how are you planning to render your components without such state?

Comment: Using props, I assume?

Comment: As @HenrikAndersson said, using Props. If my understanding is correct, 'States' are merely flags. Green flag means do this, red flag means do that, blue flag means eat supper & so on...

Comment: React 0.14 made it easier to use stateless components.  I've seen a lot about this discussed lately.  Here is a link to one of the articles I read.  https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.h2lq5bd6w

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is *technically* correct that you do not need to use React's internal component state to build a React application. Of course, the data needs to live *somewhere*, so you need a mechanism which can pass all the data into the top-level component (where it will trickle down into all the other components) when the data changes.

This is the basic idea behind flux (and many other patterns designed to provide outside-of-React state storage). You have one or more *stores* and the stores provide change events when their data changes. Then that data gets passed into the application via props.

```
function render(data) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Application data={data} />,
    containerNode
  )
}

myDataStore.on('change', render);
```

In practice, however, it can be difficult to do this performantly because of how JavaScript works. Code like the above would make React re-render the entire component tree each time `myDataStore` changes, and without good `shouldComponentUpdate` hooks, this can be a performance issue. Using immutable values helps make it easier to implement good `shouldComponentUpdate` methods.

What you'll usually see in a larger React application that uses outside-of-React data storage is a combination of:

- One or more ["container" components](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) that are responsible for getting the data from the stores and passing it to their children. Sometimes it makes sense to put containers somewhere *other* than the very top of the component tree (e.g. you may have several containers in one app)
- Reusable/"presentational" components that do not hook into the data store, but provide some other benefit (such as black boxed styles, or an interactive widget). In these cases, it often makes sense to keep any non-application-specific state inside the component itself.

Comment: Thank you @MichelleTilley, I just asked this very question in my comment at DiscussReact forum. Here is the link: Any further guidance would be much appreciated. https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/getting-to-grips-with-component-heirarchy-in-react/2887

Comment: I am adopting the first point you mentioned. I.e, there are going to be a few top level containers. Thank you.

Comment: Accepting this answer as no further discussion has been contributed to the question.